# Find type of singularities of $\frac{z^7}{(z^2-4)^2\cos\left(\frac{1}{z-2}\right)}.$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

Find type of singularities of
$$
\frac{z^7}{(z^2-4)^2\cos\left(\frac{1}{z-2}\right)}.
$$

So they are $z=-2,+2, 2 + \frac{1}{\frac{\pi}{2} +\pi k},k\in \mathbb{Z}$

Now $z=-2$ is second order pole.
$z=2$ is essential singularity.

Now at the answers of the book there is no mention about this points $2 + \frac{1}{\frac{\pi}{2} +\pi k}$. They are not singularities? And also there is a mention that $\infty$ is third order pole. Can you explain this part also?

Comment: We have $z^{-3}f(z)\to 1$ when $|z|\to \infty,$ hence $\infty$ is a pole of order $3.$ For $z_k=2+({\pi\over 2}+\pi k)^{-1}$ there holds $f(z)\to c_k\neq 0$ when $z\to z_k.$ Hence $z_k$ is a pole of order $1.$